# Post image in memory to a rest server

Tags: java

I use the following code to write an image that exists in memory to disk:

```
    BufferedImage image = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(productBrandImage.getImage(), null);
    BufferedImage imageRGB = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.BITMASK);
    Graphics2D graphics = imageRGB.createGraphics();
    graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

    File imgFile = Utilities.constructImagePathForProductBrand(imageName);

    ImageIO.write(imageRGB, "png",
            imgFile);
    graphics.dispose();
```

And elsewhere in the program use the following code to upload the image in disk to a REST server:

```
    HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
    HttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);

    MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    entityBuilder.addPart("filea", new FileBody(filea));
    entityBuilder.addPart("fileb", new FileBody(fileb));

    final HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
    httpPost.setEntity(entity);

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Now I want to directly post the image file in the memory to the server without writing to the disk first. (For some cases, it is not necessary to write the image to the disk.)

I know that `MultipartEntityBuilder` has an `addBinaryBody(String name, InputStream stream)` method but I don't have in-depth knowledge of how streams work to make the two parts work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ImageIO for writting to a stream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(imageRGB, "png", stream);
```

then add the binary body to the post request

```
MultipartEntityBuilder multiPartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multiPartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("Picture", stream.toByteArray(), ContentType.create("image/png"), "image.png");
httpPost.setEntity(multiPartEntityBuilder.build());
```